# R shiny application stops execution of code after closing

Tags: r, shiny

This Shiny UI is placed within a larger code piece. When I run my code the execution of code after the application stops sometime after closing not always in the same place and without error. The code without the application runs fine and does not stop. Is there a way I need to be calling a shiny app within my R code?

Version info:

```
version
               _                                
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32               
arch           x86_64                           
os             mingw32                          
crt            ucrt                             
system         x86_64, mingw32                  
status                                          
major          4                                
minor          2.2                              
year           2022                             
month          10                               
day            31                               
svn rev        83211                            
language       R                                
version.string R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
nickname       Innocent and Trusting
```

The code example:

```
commonnames <- c("aaaple", "peear", "banana","pare","kiwwi","bannnana")
vector <-  c("apple", "pear", "banana","orange","kiwi","mango","grapes")

library(shiny)
# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Brands To Match To"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      width = 10,
      hr("Common User Entered Words:"),
      hr(),
      x <- (paste(commonnames, collapse = ", ")),
      hr(),
      textInput("word1", vector[1]),
      textInput("word2", vector[2]),
      textInput("word3", vector[3]),
      textInput("word4", vector[4]),
      textInput("word5", vector[5]),
      textInput("word6", vector[6]),
      textInput("word7", vector[7]),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      width = 10,
      actionButton("save", "Save")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  words <- reactiveValues(words = list())

  observeEvent(input$save, {
    words$words <- list(
      word1 = input$word1,
      word2 = input$word2,
      word3 = input$word3,
      word4 = input$word4,
      word5 = input$word5,
      word6 = input$word6,
      word7 = input$word7
    )
  })

  observe({
    assign("words", words$words, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  })

  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    stopApp()
  })
}

# Run the application ----
shinyApp(ui, server)


#Additional R code below here after exiting application does not run
```

Comment: I dont understand your question. Your code works fine for me.

Comment: I have code that continues after this application and it stops running. I have edited my question to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (hijacked your save button):

```
commonnames <- c("aaaple", "peear", "banana","pare","kiwwi","bannnana")
vector <-  c("apple", "pear", "banana","orange","kiwi","mango","grapes")

library(shiny)
# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Brands To Match To"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      width = 10,
      hr("Common User Entered Words:"),
      hr(),
      x <- (paste(commonnames, collapse = ", ")),
      hr(),
      textInput("word1", vector[1]),
      textInput("word2", vector[2]),
      textInput("word3", vector[3]),
      textInput("word4", vector[4]),
      textInput("word5", vector[5]),
      textInput("word6", vector[6]),
      textInput("word7", vector[7]),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      width = 10,
      actionButton("save", "Save")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  words <- reactiveValues(words = list())
  
  observeEvent(input$save, {
    stopApp()
  })
  
  observe({
    assign("words", list(
      word1 = input$word1,
      word2 = input$word2,
      word3 = input$word3,
      word4 = input$word4,
      word5 = input$word5,
      word6 = input$word6,
      word7 = input$word7
    ), envir = .GlobalEnv)
  })
  
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    stopApp()
  })
}

# Run the application ----
shinyApp(ui, server)


# code after shiny
234567
words
```

Comment: This worked!! So strange I guess it did not like me using the x to close the application.